# Wildcard operator for variable in mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql, variables, wildcard

I have a `mysql_query` that must have `WHERE columnName = '$variable1'` in it. For example:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM database WHERE columnName = '$variable1'");
```

I want the contents of `$variable1` to retrieve any value in ColumnName; sort of like a wildcard operator. I have tried using an asterisk (`*`) like this:

```
$variable1 = '*'
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM database WHERE columnName = '$variable1'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // Echo the content of ALL ROWS IN TABLE here
}
```

The result of this query, when echoed, should display all the rows in the database. The asterisk does not work as a universal variable, nor does a blank space (e.g. `$variable = ''`). What is the wildcard operator in MySQL that would match all text combinations?

Comment: `if($var == '*') $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM database.table"); else $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM database.table WHERE columnName = '$variable1'");` what about this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the wildcard character in SQL is `%`. And you need to use `LIKE` instead of `=` for wildcard matching.
For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE ColumnHas LIKE "%something%";
```

This example will match any string that has "something" in the middle, such as

```
"This is something to match".
```

If you want wildcard match only at the beginning of the string, then exclude the trailing `%` (and vice versa).

For your case,

```
$variable1 = '%'
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM database WHERE columnName LIKE '$variable1'");
```

should work.

But your use case makes me think no wildcard matching is necessary. You can also use

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM database WHERE columnName NOT NULL");
```

provided `columnName` is defined to hold `NULL` as default value.

Comment: Is it possible to use two wildcards for two separate columns? For example: `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM database WHERE column1 LIKE % AND column2 LIKE %");`

Comment: @JSW189 Yes, it is perfectly acceptable to use multiple wildcards in a single query.

Comment: @zsaat14 is right. You can use as many `LIKE`s as you like in a single `WHERE` clause. I just want to warn you that wildcard matching with `LIKE` can be **BAD** performance wise. It may result in table sweeps.

Comment: Please be careful scaling this up. Both the `LIKE '%matchstring'` and the `NOT NULL` matching instructions definitively defeat the use of indexes for searching.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
$variable1 = "' OR 1 = 1;"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve rows with any value in a particular column, you simply refrain from mentioning that column in a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: That would be a simple solution, but the code needs the `WHERE` clause there. Is there any other way to work around this? Like a wildcard operator?

Comment: If you absolutely must have the where clause that does nothing, you can use `WHERE 1 = 1`